# Best way to make a function which can take a list or any number of arguments?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, arguments

What's the correct way of implementing the `for_each` function so that it can take any number of argument or a list or a tuple as parameter?

```
def do_something(arg):
    print("done", arg)


def for_each(func, *args):
    if len(args) == 1:  # How to do this, since this gives an
        args = args[0]  # error if there's only one parameter besides func?
    for arg in args:
        func(arg)


for_each(do_something, 1, 2)
for_each(do_something, ['foo', 'bar'])
for_each(do_something, (3, 4, 5))
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> done 1
> done 2
> done foo
> done bar
> done 3
> done 4
> done 5
> ```

What's the correct way to achieve this? Since this will break if called like this:

```
for_each(do_something, 1)
```

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "main.py", line 12, in <module>
>     for_each(do_something, 1)
>   File "main.py", line 8, in for_each
>     for arg in args:
> TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
> ```

Comment: are you trying to use map?, I can not understand what is the problem with args being a list, or using list comprehension or map, you can do def for_each(func, args): return [func(arg) for arg in args

Comment: @E.Serra I just want the users of my function to be able to use it with either as passing a list or passing the arguments individually. This is just a very simplified example.

Comment: @ruohola The first version of my function should be fine for you then, just check if it is an iterable from `collections.abc.Iterable` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to check if your first element is a list or a tuple like this:

(You need to check the instance, in case user just use a single int for instance, your code would fail)

```
def for_each(func, *args):
  if len(args) == 1 and (isinstance(args[0], tuple) or isinstance(args[0], list)): # You can even check on Iterable by importing collections.abc.Iterable
    args = args[0]
  for arg in args:
    func(arg)
```

However, you can go further and let the user input several `Iterable` and not only tuples or lists, such as follow :

```
from collections.abc import Iterable
from itertools import chain


def do_something(arg):
    print("done", arg)

def for_each(func, *args):
  if all(map(lambda x: isinstance(x, Iterable), args)) and not any(map(lambda x: isinstance(x, str), args)):
    args = chain(*args)
  for arg in args:
    func(arg)


for_each(do_something, [0, 1], [0, 2])
```

Comment: what if they pass a set?, and an int, your all will fail the is instance, e.g. for_each(print, [23, ['a', 'b']])

Comment: @E.Serra OP did not ask for a dfs or a bfs of his args, as far as I understood, he is asking for a depth of 1. He did not even ask for the second method, it is just an help for the OP.(I do not know if you downvoted this post, but avoid it for revenge please)

Comment: @E.Serra This doesn't need to handle nested lists

Comment: FYI: This doesn't work if the argument is a single string. But then again the OP has not mentioned this.

Comment: @quamrana I want this to work for any types of arguments, so it should work for any number of strings or a list/tuple of string also.

Comment: @quamrana This is fixed, thanks, my first version (what op asked) works fine for strings. Thanks for mentionning, on the second version I am now testing if there is a string inside `args` !

Comment: @ruohola, I updated it to avoid printing character by character if there is a list, does it answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Ok now that I understand your question:

don't do this:

```
if len(args) == 1:  # is there really no cleaner
    args = args[0]  # way to do this part?
```

This looks prettier imho as long as you don't need to return, just want to call a function.

```
def for_each(func, *args):
    for arg in args: 
        if any([isinstance(args, myiter) for myiter in [tuple, list, set]]): 
            [for_each(func, arg) for arg in args]
        else:
            func(args)



for_each(do_something, 1, 2) 
for_each(do_something, ['foo', 'bar']) 
for_each(do_something, (3, 4, 5))                                                                                                                                                              
done 1
done 2
done foo
done bar
done 3
done 4
done 5
for_each(do_something, 1)                                                                                                                                                                      
done 1
```