# Pythonic way to make a function which can take an iterable or any number of arguments?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, arguments

Is this really the most Pythonic way to make a function which can take an iterable or any number of arguments and do something with each of them?

```
from collections.abc import Iterable


def for_each(*args):
    """Take any number of arguments or an iterable and do something with them.
    Shouldn't throw an error or print anything when no arguments are given.
    """
    if (len(args) == 1
            and isinstance(args[0], Iterable)
            and not isinstance(args[0], str)):
        # Is this really the most Pythonic way to do this?
        args = args[0]

    for arg in args:
        # heavily simplified
        print("done", arg)


for_each(1, 2)
for_each(['foo', 'bar'])
for_each((3, 4, 5))
for_each()  # does essentially nothing, like it should
for_each("string")  # don't loop over the characters
for_each(6)
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> done 1
> done 2
> done foo
> done bar
> done 3
> done 4
> done 5
> done string
> done 6
> ```

I got this working answer [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55499233/9835872), but since I was actually looking for a cleaner way to do this, I made this new question.

This works, but in my opinion the checking is quite ugly and **I was hoping there would be simpler, cleaner way to achieve this**. **The output should remain the same.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Pythonic way is *don't*. Pick one, and let the caller provide the correct argument(s):

```
# Iterable only: caller wraps the arguments
def for_each(iterable=None):
    if iterable is None:
        iterable = ()
        # or just return now, if that's an option

    for arg in iterable:
        ...

foreach((1,2,3))

# separate args: caller unpacks the arguments
def for_each(*args):
    for arg in args:
        ...

x = [1,2,3]
for_each(*x)
```

There is no good way to do it like you want, because you are inherently trying to guess the caller's intentions. You have to count the number of arguments, and then you have to worry about types like str that look like iterables but aren't, or maybe they should be.

**If it has to be done the way you want, your original example is about as good as you can get, but it is still flawed.** Suppose the user wants to treat a string as in iterable; your approach still requires them to write for_each(["foo"]), in which case, why complicate your function's implementation for no reason.

Comment: Yes I'm very aware that most of the time it would be best to just force the function user to pass parameters in a specific format. The question is not about best practices generally, it's about *the best way to implement such a function*.

Comment: There is no good way, because you are inherently trying to guess the caller's intentions. You *have* to count the number of arguments, and then you have to worry about types like `str` that look like iterables but aren't, or maybe they should be.

Comment: So are you saying that my original example is perfect and has nothing to improve on? I understand that there is no *good way*, but there has to be a way which is better than others.

Comment: No, I'm saying your original is about as good as you can get, but it is still flawed. Suppose the user *wants* to treat a string as in iterable; your approach still requires them to write `for_each(["foo"])`, in which case, why complicate your function's implementation for no reason?

Comment: In an ideal world, either `str` instances would not be iterable at all, or there would be a distinct `char` type which iterating over a `str` would yield. Even then, though, that doesn't necessarily stop someone from writing their *own* type which implements this iterator-of-its-own-type nonsense.